# Where did lt_index go?

Tags: coq

I was using a lemma named `lt_index` in coq, I remember it states that

```
n < 2 * m + 1 -> (n - 1) / 2 < m
```

Now, I can't use this lemma anymore, and when I do `SearchAbout lt_index`, coq answers with

```
Error: The reference lt_index was not found in the current environment.
```

My imports are as follows

```
Require Import Coq.Numbers.Natural.Peano.NPeano.
Require Import Arith.
```

Did I miss something?

EDIT: Apparently, I dreamed about this `lt_index` lemma and never existed. Anyway, I came up with a proof to the same result, I added `1 <= n` as precondition. Here it is

```
Lemma lt_solve:forall (n m:nat), 1 <= n -> n < 2 * m + 1 -> (n - 1) / 2 < m.
Proof.
intros.
assert (n <= n - 1 + 1).
apply Nat.sub_add_le.
inversion H1.
rewrite <-H2.
rewrite H2 in H0.
rewrite plus_comm in H0.
assert (2*m+1=1+2*m).
apply plus_comm.
rewrite H3 in H0.
apply plus_lt_reg_l in H0.
apply Nat.div_lt_upper_bound in H0.
trivial.
discriminate.
rewrite plus_comm in H2.
rewrite (le_plus_minus_r 1 n) in H2.
eapply (le_lt_trans n m0 (S m0)) in H3.
rewrite H2 in H3.
contradict H3.
apply lt_irrefl.
apply lt_n_Sn.
trivial.
Qed.
```

If you realize there is an improvement to this proof, I'd be glad to hear about it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the link between the lemma and its name, are you sure this was ever part of the std lib of Coq ?

Comment: Yeah that doesn't ring a bell, and rgrep returns nothing interesting either.

Comment: Never mind, it seems I had this lemma admitted somewhere in my code, and deleted it. I edited my post and gave a solution. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is good to try to solve these kinds of problems by hand as an exercise, in the long run it can get tedious, if you really want to work on something else.

There are tactics that can help you to solve systems of equations with inequalities. You can for instance use the tactics `lia` from `Psatz`, or `omega` from `Omega`.  The proof terms are not a pretty sight, but if that doesn't matter then why not.

Unfortunately they don't handle division, so they can't solve this system, but there is a lemma in the library that you can use to get rid of the `/`.  I found it by doing `Search ( _ / _ < _ ).`

```
Require Import Coq.Numbers.Natural.Peano.NPeano.
Require Import Psatz. (* this provides 'lia' for solving linear integer arithmetic *)

Lemma lt_solve:forall (n m:nat), 
   1 <= n -> n < 2 * m + 1 -> (n - 1) / 2 < m.
Proof.
   intros; apply Nat.div_lt_upper_bound; lia.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks @larsr. It worked pretty nice! Two observations. One, after `apply Nat.div_lt_upper_bound` I had to prove that 2<>0. I did it with the `intuition` tactic. Two, the execution of this proof produces a file `lia.cache`, I wonder why this file was created.

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason would like to get a "manual" solution, using the standard library, then here it is.

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Lemma lt_solve : forall (n m:nat),
    1 <= n -> n < 2 * m + 1 -> (n - 1) / 2 < m.
Proof with auto.
  intros.
  apply Nat.div_lt_upper_bound...
  destruct n.
  - inversion H.
  - rewrite Nat.sub_succ.
    rewrite Nat.sub_0_r.
    rewrite (Nat.add_lt_mono_r _ _ 1).
    rewrite Nat.add_1_r...
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks @Anton, one question: why did you add `Proof with auto` at the very beginning of your proof? What is the role of `with auto`?

Comment: It's just a shortcut. The construction `Proof with <tactic>` works as follows. When you see ellipsis (`...`) ending a tactic `t1`, it's equivalent to turning it into `t1; <tactic>`. So `rewrite Nat.add_1_r...` behaves as `rewrite Nat.add_1_r; auto`.